# Track logged in users' visits

Tags: users

Is there a way to track logged in user activity? I'd like to see who logged in to the site each day and maybe see a specific persons login history.

Currently I have no idea which of the registered users are visiting my site. It's a private family site with **~20 members** and I'm just curious to know who is and who isn't using it.

Answer (score 2):

As it's a small site, you can do some "real" tracking:

```
// Update the visit time on *every* request
function wpse32258_update_usertracking(){
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user_ID = get_current_user_id();

        $data = get_user_meta( $user_ID, 'user_tracking' );
        $data[] = current_time( 'timestamp', true );

        update_user_meta( $user_ID, 'user_tracking', $data );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse32258_update_usertracking' );

// Output the user visit dates below the footer for admin
function wpse32258_get_usertracking(){
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
        return;

    $data = array();
    foreach ( get_users() as $user ){
        $dates = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'user_tracking' );
        echo "<h3>{$user->first_name} {$user->last_name}</h3><hr />";
        foreach ( $dates as $date )
            echo "{$date}\n";
        echo '<hr />';
    }
}
add_action( 'shutdown', 'wpse32258_get_usertracking' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the plugins listed here, and while some of them were really cool I felt like there were some things lacking.

So recently some friends and I released a plugin called **[Stream](http://wordpress.org/plugins/stream/)** which tracks every change made by logged-in WordPress users.

The plugin is similar to the ones listed here except that every change is organized by user, context, action and IP address to allow for robust filtering/searching.

More information:

- http://www.wptavern.com/stream-a-wordpress-plugin-to-track-and-monitor-changes-in-the-admin
- http://x-team.com/2013/12/stream-track-every-change-made-on-your-wordpress-site/
- https://github.com/x-team/wp-stream

Comment: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem.

Answer (score -1):

You may try these plugins:

- **[Simple history](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-history/)**
- [ThreeWP Activity Monitor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/threewp-activity-monitor/)

Or you may check this articles about log user activity plugins:

- http://wpmu.org/wordpress-activity-log/
- http://www.thewebdesignbay.com/wordpress/wordpress-plugins-track-users-statistics

Comment: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there a way to track logged in user activity in wordpress. With help of One WordPress Plugin use can easily track and monitor user's login and activity. I would like you to check this Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-activity-log/
I'm sure you would satisfy with it.

Comment: link only answers are useless. Please edit you answer and expand on how exactly can that plugin be used to answer the question.