# How to keep track of user logins?

Tags: users, login, private, statistics

I have a client with a private Wordpress blog - that is to say, you need to log in to read it.

We are using Counterize to keep track of visits to the site and to find the most popular pages.

But now he wants to know which users are logging in, and perhaps how often they are logging in to read this blog.

I checked to see if there was any info in wp_usermeta ( like last-login-date ) but there doesn't seem to be.

Any suggestions how to keep track of user's activities?

Thanks

Comment: you can probably find some examples to get you started in the related questions column ->

Answer (score 5):

A basic user login tracker is pretty trivial to implement.

```
function track_user_login_wpse_100929($id,$user) {
  $tracking = get_user_meta($user->ID,'tracking_key_name',true); 
  $tracking[] = time();
  update_user_meta($user->ID,'tracking_key_name',$tracking);
}
add_action('wp_login','track_user_login_wpse_100929',1,2);
```

After that you just need to work out the details such as how long you are going to keep the history, what kind of reports you want to pull, that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wordpress plugin [Simple Login Log](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-login-log/)

This plugin keeps a log of WordPress user logins. Offers user and date filtering, and export features.

**Important Links**:

[5 Handy WordPress Plugins to Track Users and Statistics](http://www.thewebdesignbay.com/wordpress/wordpress-plugins-track-users-statistics)

[Track logged in users' visits](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32258/track-logged-in-users-visits)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the logged in time of users yo ucan take  http://wordpress.org/plugins/hrm-work-tracking